# Laravel 5.5 cashier test subscriptions with short trial

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, saas

I tested web site subscriptions users through stripe.   Website uses php laravel 5.5 with cashier on linux server.

How to make a short grace period for tests?

I use this code:

```
    $user->newSubscription('main', $request->get('subs_type'))
      ->trialUntil(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(330))
      ->create($request->get('stripeToken'), [
        'email' => $user->email,
    ]);
```

instead of the usual

```
    $user->newSubscription('main', $request->get('subs_type'))
      ->trialDays(1)
      ->create($request->get('stripeToken'), [
        'email' => $user->email,
    ]);
```

But after the end of the short trial laravel cashier method onTrial() returns true. Since the method compares dates, not hours or minutes.

```
     /**
     * Determine if the subscription is within its trial period.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function onTrial()
    {
        if (! is_null($this->trial_ends_at)) {
            return Carbon::today()->lt($this->trial_ends_at);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Are there any practices that will correct this.

Of course, I do not have to edit the source of laravel